# WCF Windows Authentication Error

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I'm trying to consume a Service with an WCF Console Application. But the only thing I get as a Response is "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request."

The Service is configured with the following options:

```
<services>
  <service name="TryOut.BasicService" behaviorConfiguration="NicksBasicBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.10.67:8000/Service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address ="http://192.168.10.67:8000/Service"

              name="NicksEndpoint"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="TryOut.IBasicService"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
              />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NicksBasicBehavior">       
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<binding name="BasicBinding">
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

The configuration file of my Client is the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NicksEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.10.67:8000/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="NicksEndpoint" contract="ServiceReference1.IBasicService"
      name="NicksEndpoint" />
</client>
```

Now everything works fine when I'm starting the client on the same PC as the service. But if I'm try to running the Client on a machine which is not in the domain of the server PC then I get an error, although I provide the Login information's in the client code:

```
c.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Nick", "password", "mydomain");
```

Does anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanking you in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949012.aspx), it looks as if you need to specify your credentials differently:

```
WCFTestService.Service myService = new WCFTestService.Service();
myService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
MessageBox.Show(myService.GetData(123, true));
myService.Dispose();
```

Could you try to use this code and try to pass the Windows credentials into `myService.Credentials` ? Does that work?

Marc

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifing the userPrincipalName in the identity element on your clients endpoint?